# How to find the height of the var that has html content in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

```
function appData (arg) {
    var tmp ='<div  class="eventPopUp" z-index:6;">asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd<div style="clear:"></div></div>'
    $(arg).html(tmp);
    var off= $(tmp).offset().left;
    var wid = $(tmp).width();
    //var hei = $(arg).children().height();
    var hei = $(tmp).outerHeight();


    console.log('width is ' + wid + ' height is ' + hei);
 }
```

Hi in above function i am making a variable that has html  elements in it and i  want to know the `height` and `width` of the tmp variable(becasue the content gets updated dynamically) My problem is i can get the `width` of the variable tmp by using `width()` method and i am getting `height` 0 by using `height()` method. please help me to find the height of the var `tmp`. and if i explictly give height by using style then height() method is giving proper answer and arg is 'li' were i append this varible.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any method/approach which can find the height/width of element that has not been created yet.

Comment: what is arg, of which HTML is being updated?

Comment: You're using your tmp as your selector. So jQuery is looking for a selector `'<div  class="eventPopUp" z-index:6;">asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd<div style="clear:"></div></div>'`

If I understand you, you need to change `tmp` to `this.div` assuming it is the div that you've created that you're trying to get the dimensions of.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery seems to be confused as to exactly which element you are selecting when doing `$(tmp)` and therefore returns an empty height.

If you define the string as an object explicitly on initialisation, the height can be calculated once it's attached to the DOM. Try this:

```
function appData(arg) {
    var $tmp = $('<div class="eventPopUp">asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd <br> asdfasd<div style="clear:"></div></div>')
    $(arg).append($tmp);

    var off = $tmp.offset().left;
    var wid = $tmp.width();
    var hei = $tmp.outerHeight();   

    console.log('width is ' + wid + ' height is ' + hei);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNKZM/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting 0, is most likely because you are reading the height before the element has any content in it. In other words, try using [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// call appData function here
});
```

If this doesn't work, try using setTimeout

```
x = setTimeout(function() {
// call appData or read height and if height of my selection is != 0 then
// {
// clearTimeout(x);
// myHeight = height of my selection
// call function that does something with it and send it as a param
// }
}, 1000);
```

You check for the height every second until the height is different from 0. This is a hack, I don't recommend it, unless you start leaving forehead marks on the wall.